# Generate Kolmogorov-Chapman equations for Markov processes

Tags: python, math, markov-chains, markov, mathcad

I am looking for a way to generate Kolmogorov-Chapman equations for MathCad to solve Markov Chain problem. 
Problem is to find probability of the system being in one of the states. System has N components.
I have a graph with 2^N nodes (states), and 2*N parameter: N `a`'s, which is probability that Nth component will break down and N `b`'s, which is the probability that broken component will become healthy again.

N can be close to 10, which means, that there will be 1024 equations at least, so I'm looking for a way to generate these equations.

Mathcad is not a requirement, any other math engine is OK (even Python if then can be solved with smth like `scipy`)

Comment: Start by writing one equation, then generalize that.  What does "looking for a way to generate" mean?  Are you having trouble writing the equations or programming them?  The former is not a good SO question; the latter might be if you'd post the code you've written.

Comment: Are you using the probability matrix form of the Makov Chain?  If so you just need matrix multiplication. [Matrix Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5P4kCpdhho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is to find probability of the system being in one of the states.

As your stochastic process is a combination of N *independent* Markov chains, the problem is much easier to approach by solving the equations for each chain separately than solving a system of 2<sup>2*N</sup> equations for the whole process.

The transition matrix for an individual chain is:

[image]

So, the Kolmogorov-Chapman equations are:

[image]

[image]

And if you still need the equations for the entire system:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the power-iteration might be a good heuristic? (only for well-behaved systems, I guess)

Comment: @wildplasser I don't think you need power-iteration to calculate a 2x2 matrix raised to a power (or the limit of such matrices, or their eigenvectors). All of it can be done analytically.